# Transfer contacts from local phone storage to iCloud account

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts

I just noticed that all my new contacts was saved to local phone storage instead of iCloud (I saw Settings – Mail, Contacts, Calendars – Contacts – Default account – “On iPhone”). How to transfer all my local storage contacts back to iCloud?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you enable contacts in iCloud settings it should ask you to do so. 
If it is enabled already, perhaps try to turn it off and on again?

Comment: yes, it helps me. I not longer see local contacts storage, only iCloud now.

Comment: Turning off iCloud contacts, iOS 8 will ask you if you'd like to keep them on your phone, say yes, then turn iCloud contacts back on, and it will auto-import everything from your phone to iCloud. This had me stymied for a few days but it worked, and imported everything.